# Не работает keyup во Vue

Tags: vue.js

Хочу чтобы при нажатии на Enter в input-е срабатывало событие.
Вешаю на keyup обработчик `suggestMenuOnEnter`.
В скомпиленном файле ставлю точку отладки и alert - до нее не доходит.
Ошибок нет.

Js:

```
methods: {
    suggestMenuOnEnter: function() {
        alert(12344);
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<b-form-input
    id="address"
    type="text"
    name="address"
    v-model="device.address"
    autocomplete="off"
    @keyup.enter="suggestMenuOnEnter"
    :class="{
        'bs-callout-success': device.positionStatus == 0,
        'bs-callout-info':    device.positionStatus == 1,
        'bs-callout-danger':  device.positionStatus == 2
    }"
    data-value="{{ $deviceUsing->address }}"></b-form-input>
```

Почему не заходит в suggestMenuOnEnter при нажатии на Enter в этом поле?

Comment: попробуй @keyup.native.enter

Comment: Отлично, помогло